# Runtime error on test 1 (Code Forces) but workes in netbeans

Tags: java

I am new to code forces, when i run this code in NetBeans its works correctly but when I submit it on code forces it gives me Runtime error on test 1. what is the wrong? 
This is the [problem](https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/158/A)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String first = input.nextLine();
    String second = input.nextLine();
    input.close();

    String first_line[] = first.split(" ");
    String second_line[] = second.split(" ");
    int first_numbers[] = new int[first_line.length];
    int second_numbers[] = new int[second_line.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        if (Integer.parseInt(first_line[i]) >= 1)
            first_numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(first_line[i]);
        else
            first_numbers[i] = 0;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < second_line.length; i++)
        if (Integer.parseInt(second_line[i]) >= 1)
            second_numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(second_line[i]);
        else
            second_numbers[i] = 0;
    int x = 0;
    try {
        for (int i = 0; first_numbers[1] < second_numbers[i]; i++)
            x++;
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you modify your last for loop as below

```
int x = 0;
for (int i=0; i<second_numbers.length; i++) {
    if (first_numbers[1] < second_numbers[i])
        x++;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

why you split String int those

```
   String first_line[] = first.split(" ");
   String second_line[] = second.split(" ");
   int first_numbers[] = new int[first_line.length];
   int second_numbers[] = new int[second_line.length];
```

you can initialize int from the beginning and use it 2 int  like the following

```
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int k = input.nextInt();
        int n = input.nextInt();
        int cout = 0;
        int[] arr = new int[k];
```

and here you are my complete solution for this problem from 2014

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = input.nextInt();
        int k = input.nextInt();
        int counter = 0, tk = 0;
        int a[] = new int[n];

        for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
            a[i] = input.nextInt();
            if((i + 1) == k){
                tk = a[i];
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
            if(a[i] > 0 && a[i] >= tk){
                counter++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(counter);
    }
```

i wish i can help

if i can advice you 
            try to make it simple as much as you can in these problem at beginning.